# Is this question off-topic for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Is question *[Any debugger for Java 8 Nashorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33016540)* off-topic for Stack Overflow?

I'd say yes, but there's some back-and-forth.

I'm actually a bit ambivalent about this one since it's directly related to a programming problem, although as worded the question seems clearly off-topic.

(The question has been deleted. I also don't think piling on downvotes on the original question is a particularly useful response either.)

Comment: How can  _"Is there any dubugger for Nashorn, like Blink Developer Tools ?"_ NOT be off-topic?

Comment: I love how people ALWAYS fight back closure with "but it would be useful to me".... when that's not at all what's problematic about the question. First time I see users with such rep using that type of argument though. No matter how useful or "hard" it is, if the question is "is there any debugger for X", it HAS to be a tools request, whether it's useful or not for people is irrelevant.

Comment: Not sure how much more-canonical an "off-site resource request" you could ask for. No code, no specific problem -- or even problem *area* -- to solve. Just "point me to a debugger".

Comment: @Patrice ... I specifically state it's OT.

Comment: @DaveNewton and you also ask "is this OT for SO" in your title ;) So you ARE on the fence

Comment: By OT do you mean on-topic or off-topic? It's definitely off-topic.

Comment: @Patrice I *am* on the fence despite it being OT, particularly as worded.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's been my experience that OT on SO always means off-topic, but you're right, it's ambiguous.

Comment: Its a sharp pointy fence too, ouch ouch. I want to punch through the software recommendation bit and read it as "how do you bloody debug javascript code run through nashorn". I'd really want to know the answer to that question.

Comment: I believe it is off-topic but there is confusion on these types of things. The confusion probably stems from this part in the help center "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is" which I take it to mean a *specific* problem with a *specific* tool. But **not** asking for suggestions on one to use. I don't think everyone needs to get upset about this question but that's my thoughts.

Comment: @Gimby Then it's OT for being too broad ;) I have a slight disagreement with SO about *some* questions like this, but since I agree it's *generally* not great asking for libraries/tools/etc I have to go in whole-hog. I just don't think Recommendations SE is busy enough for something as specific as this, or that there are enough options of tools. It's a pretty technical, highly-focused tool that's required.

Comment: @DaveNewton don't agree, its very narrow. Specifically about Nashorn.

Comment: *" also don't think piling on downvotes on the original question is a particularly useful response either"* probably not but people deleting it while it's being discussed probably isn't particularly useful either.

Comment: The downvotes aren't a problem, since it got deleted. The OP won't lose rep over it.

Comment: @Gimby My issue is with the wording, "how do I debug".

Comment: Oh, and I hardly think _1_ person claiming it's "on topic" constitutes a "discussion".

Comment: @Cerbrus That's true; I originally read it wrong and thought there were two people saying it's on-topic.

Comment: @DaveNewton there we agree, it would need editing for sure.

Comment: @Gimby: If by _"editing"_ you mean _"complete re-write so the question is about a specific programming problem"_, I agree.

Comment: Technically an edit ;)

Comment: @cerbrus yes exactly, but I wouldn't do that without verifying in the comments that the complete re-write is actually what the original intent behind the question was.

Comment: Frankly, I don't see how the current intent (_is there a debugger X?_) can be rewritten to a _specific programming problem_.

Comment: @Cerbrus the possibility to debug code is a pretty nifty programming problem, its just a shame the guy instantly made the jump to looking for external tools rather than investigating the one they are already using (Java 8 + Nashorn).

Comment: So, then it'd be a _"How do I debug X"_ -question, not? That seems to be "Too broad".

Comment: Yeah, I don't see how a "how do I debug Nashorn [in general]" can't be too broad. SO is explicitly for specific programming problems. I guess if I had to articulate my fenciness it's that the problem here is hyper-focused and ultimately technical enough that the best answer(s) would come from the SO population. Yes, it's OT (like I said) but... meh.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you need to give up about half your rep for this question.  I'll hold onto it for you, don't worry.

Comment: Fair enough! ;)

Comment: Yes​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was one of the close voters.

The question is a two-liner very explicitly asking for a debugger which is an off-site resource:

> Is there any dubugger for Nashorn, like Blink Developer Tools ?

Off-site resource requests are off-topic for StackOverflow as per the help center.

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

If you are in need of a software, the [Software Recs SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) is here for you (their [help center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).

As a matter of fact the question has been deleted for *reasons of moderation*.

Comment: I  voted to delete the question because 1: It negates the rep loss for the OP, and 2: The question is of no value to the site. (Especially when closed, as it should be)

Comment: Sssh I have a dubugger for you, give me some cash and wait here